# No me muestra el console.log() de la prueba

Tags: javascript, web, funciones

Se supone que al tocar los items de una lista me devuelva en consola 'Existe'. Pero no lo reconoce ni hace nada.

```
<ul id="items" class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">
    Item 1
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right eliminar">X</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Item 2
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right eliminar">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

El pedazo del código donde estan las listas es este.
Y el código de javascript que no me funciona es este

```
function quitarItem(c){
    if(c.target.classList.contains('eliminar')){
        console.log('existe');
    }
}
```

Comment: prueba con `document.getElementsByClassName("eliminar");`

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, era una tonteria.
En vez de

```
formulario.addEventListener('click', quitarItem);
```

Era:

```
lista.addEventListener('click', quitarItem);
```

Dejo esta pregunta igual por si a alguien mas le pasa